# Is it possible to force a specific number of neurons to be fired at any one time in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 2.0. I am aware of dropout and regularization techniques, however I am wondering if there is a way to specifically control the number of fired neurons in a given layer at any one time?

For example, consider a layer with 4 neurons - A, B, C and D. ReLU is used as the activation for all of these neurons. For any training/testing sample, I only want exactly 3 neurons fired, no less and no more. Therefore, the possible patterns are:

```
 1) A,B,C fired, D not fired
 2) A,B,D fired, C not fired
 3) A,C,D fired, B not fired
 4) B,C,D fired, A not fired
```

Is there any method to enforce such a constraint on a layer?

Note: I use the term "fired neuron" to denote that it has a non-zero output. A neuron not fired gives a 0 as output.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to implement that, although it is more computationally expensive than regular dropout.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def dropout_by_num(inp, n, scale=True, axis=-1):
    # Get random value with the shape of input
    s = tf.shape(inp)
    r = tf.random.uniform(s)
    # Find sort indices
    idx = tf.argsort(r, axis=axis)
    # Mask indices greater or equal to n
    mask = tf.dtypes.cast(idx < n, inp.dtype)
    if scale:
        # Scale up to preserve expected value
        m = tf.dtypes.cast(s[axis], inp.dtype)
        scale = m / tf.dtypes.cast(n, inp.dtype)
        mask *= scale
    return inp * mask

# Test
tf.random.set_seed(0)
inp = tf.ones((3, 4))
out = dropout_by_num(inp, 3)
tf.print(out)
# [[1.33333337 1.33333337 1.33333337 0]
#  [1.33333337 1.33333337 1.33333337 0]
#  [1.33333337 0 1.33333337 1.33333337]]
```